# Customise default text in combobox

Tags: css, wordpress, combobox, sidebar

I have two combo boxes in my [website](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/) in the sidebar:

[image: screenshot]

On my iPad the default phrase in the combos (**Select Month** / **Select Category**) is hard to read. Google Chrome on my PC does not have this issue.

Can this be improved with CSS styling?

Answer (score 0):

You can do device specific media queries

Example:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) 
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)
```

Create new style within these media queries